# Why isn't my PlayStation 3 controller turning on?

Tags: ps3, controllers, emulation

I am wanting to use a PS3 controller for emulators like PCSX2. When I plug in my PS3 controller with all of the necessary drivers while fully function and the USB installs drivers which function properly, my controller still isn't turning on. In my Drivers, I see under "Unspecified", "PLAYSTATION (R) 3 CONTROLLER". Is there a way to turn on my PS3 controller without making it go to my console?

Comment: Dumb question: But did you try pressing the PS button on the controller (pressing it once, not holding it)?

Comment: @Powerlord Yes I did.

Comment: Depending on how you installed the driver software, it may be on but the lights may just be inactive. Try going into PCSX2 and fiddling with the Pad settings?

Comment: Also, what steps did you take to install the drivers? Did you use Motioninjoy or did you do a manual method?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I used Motioninjoy.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf My pad wouldn't show up on Motioninjoy either and just says, "Waiting for Pads to be connected". Is there a way to fix that or use another method?

Comment: Okay, I've had better luck setting things up on my own, following a tutorial from Youtube. I can post a link to the video as an answer, I never had good luck with Motioninjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motioninjoy is a risky tool to use - it works well most of the time, but it spawn its own Internet popups and can generally be a pain to maintain. You will need to run Motioninjoy each time you unplug and replug the controller as well. Furthermore, if you leave your device plugged in and Motioninjoy running, blue screen crashes can occur when trying to put a computer to sleep, and sometimes during shutdown.

I have personally had better luck doing things manually, following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpSaOJJIun8) tutorial. It walks through step by step what to do. Essentially, it fools the computer into using Xbox 360 controller drivers with a PS3 controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the "Drivers" section of Motionjoy. Check each driver and install them. Then, it should detect your controller!

Comment: I have to do this every time I plug a controller into a different USB slot.  Also sometimes I randomly have to do it again.